# Multiple .dat files - possible using VMWare ThinApp?

Tags: vmware-thinapp

In VMWare ThinApp can a package have more than 1 .dat file ?
The name "primary data container" seems to imply that there could be more than one.

BTW I haven't encountered this yet in any of the packages I created.

Comment: Can I ask you to be much clearer and verbose with your question please as I don't fully understand it or the how it's directly linked to your tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple .dat files, you simply refer to them  by enabling the "RequiredAppLinks" parameter in Package.ini for the base application by adding the following line after the [BuildOptions] entry, "RequiredAppLinks=*secondaryname*.dat" then rebuilding.

Have a look [HERE](http://pubs.vmware.com/thinapp4/help/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm) for an example.